# Assign random material to instances on points

Tags: geometry-nodes

With the new Geometry node network (Blender 3.0.0 alpha downloaded today), how can I assign a material to a random selection of my instances? I only managed to assign two materials to a random selection of all faces of all my instances.

[image: node network]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't avoid defining the materials individually in *Geometry nodes* once. After that, however, you can instantiate the colored objects (also randomly).

This step is necessary because materials cannot be read dynamically, but are always made usable either via the existing geometry, or via the node `Set Material`.

Here is the solution:

[image]