# How to assign a different material color to each geometry nodes instance

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

I need to be able to some how color each instance in a geometry nodes tree a different color.

Each instance in the geometry nodes network is loose geometry. If I apply the geometry nodes modifier and then separate the geometry by loose parts, I can get the effect I want in the shader editor by using the Object Info node's Random output, as shown below:

[image]

However, I need to be able to get the same result *without* applying the geometry nodes modifier and separating the loose parts.

I see that there's a way to assign the material index for a piece of geometry, but it seems like this index applies for the entire mesh.

[image]

Is there any way I can pump out the ID for each instance and somehow use that in the shading editor?

I've looked at these two questions but I haven't found anything that has worked (or at least I haven't figured out how to make them work yet).
[Control Instance Color with Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213224/control-instance-color-with-geometry-nodes)

[Geometry nodes: Assign random material to instances on points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240559/geometry-nodes-assign-random-material-to-instances-on-points)

I've also watched through this video by [Entagma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOFNTZjiwP8), but it seems that Geometry Nodes' attribute system has changed such that I'm not really certain how I would apply the principles from that video.

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hello! Are you looking for a solution in 3.0 or are you open to using the beta 3.1 ?

Comment: @Gorgious 3.1 is okay! What makes the difference between 3.0 and 3.1 for this solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in 3.1 this works:

[image]

i hope you don't mind using the realize instances node...

[image]

[image]

Explanation try (i have no idea what changed from 3.0 to 3.1 - sorry about that):
The index will be "captured" by the capture attribute node from the geometry (group input) which is a cube. So it runs from 0 to 7 (which you could check by plugging in a viewer node). This index will be linked to the output so that we can use that attribute in the shader tree. This attribute will be divided by 8 because the colorramp only accepts/uses values from 0 to 1, so we get a different color for every index. Of course you would have to adapt the colorramp and the division value if you have more/less vertices.

Comment: Why do you ask if they mind using the realize instances node?

Comment: because i am not sure whether the OP wants this...

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that it was some performance issue or something, thanks :)

Comment: Beautiful, it works great! Can you explain why it works? And what changed from 3.0 to 3.1?

Comment: @Chris You've made many wonderful answers on this site, but I do sometimes think an explanation of *how* and *why* the answer works, in *addition* to the pictures, would be great.

Comment: @RayMairlot: Thank you!!! I will try...  ;)

Comment: I was implementing the technique you shared in this answer and ran into an issue where the instances get their colors randomized differently depending on which face triangle they originate from. I've opened [a new question for it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270653/). Please take a look if you don't mind.

Comment: looks like Crantisz already has a solution ;)

Comment: Yeah, that was quick! lol